# How to apply new font to characters written in a particular font?

Tags: vba, unicode, fonts, ms-word

I am editing some text files written in Coptic language using non Unicode fonts. I am converting the files to Unicode.

The files I were written using three fonts to represent pronunciation dialects.
I want to create a macro to search and replace the non Unicode characters with Unicode ones.

I want to limit the search and replace to certain fonts. I tried to record a macro, but the font choices did not record.

The end result will be replacing the characters in one of the fonts (that had dialect marks built into the character) with a Unicode character in addition to the dialect mark separately.

Is there a way to modify the code below to limit the search and replace function to the characters written in a particular font?

```
Sub aaaa()
'
' aaaa Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "n"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(11419) & ChrW(769)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

**Where to choose the font**
[image: Image showing where to choose the font]

**The end result**
[image: Image showing the end result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
    Sub twoo()
'
' twoo Macro
'
'
With Selection.Find
 .Text = "n"

 ' Clear all previously set formatting for Find dialog box.
 .ClearFormatting
 ' Set font to Find for replacement.
 .Font.Name = "EXISTING FONT NAME"


 ' Clear all previously set formatting for Replace dialog box.
 .Replacement.ClearFormatting
 ' Set font to Replace found font.
 .Replacement.Font.Name = "NEW FONT NAME"

 .Replacement.Text = ChrW(11419) & ChrW(769)
 .Forward = True
 .Wrap = wdFindContinue
 .Format = True
 .MatchCase = False
 .MatchWholeWord = False
 .MatchKashida = False
 .MatchDiacritics = False
 .MatchAlefHamza = False
 .MatchControl = False
 .MatchWildcards = False
 .MatchSoundsLike = False
 .MatchAllWordForms = False
 End With
 Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End Sub
```