# Change particularly formatted parts of text in a Word file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on MS Word documents which include text in the Ethiopic script and in Latin. The Ethiopic text parts were written in a non-Unicode encoding. Now I want to change these parts into unicode. I already managed to "write" (or create) a script (in VB I guess) that does this change. The problem I am facing now is that the original text in Latin (in German) should not be touched by the script. The Ethiopic parts have a font information which I hope can be used. Thus, I hope that there is an option which I can use in the script that help to exclusively alter only those parts of the text which have this specific font information.

This is the scrip I use

```
Selection.Font.Name = "AGF - Zemen"
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "G<"
        .Replacement.Text = ChrW(4609)
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = True
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

I never used scripts in MS Word, my main duty is the linguistic editing of the text.

Comment: Your present code would only replace "G<" with ChrW(4609). Also, while it does mention the Ethiopian font "AGF - Zemen" it doesn't specifically look for that font (observe the `Find.ClearFormatting` command, meaning no format is being looked for). I suppose that could be corrected, and then any text formatted in another font wouldn't be touched. The question is whether your document's Latin content is formatted in the Latin version of the Ethiopian font and, of course, whether it is sufficient for your needs to change just one character.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!
For clarification: 
I know that the present code will only replace one character. My idea was to learn how to correct the code and than add the same code for all the other characters.
So I had the suspicion that this code doesn't look for that specific font. But I was unable to find the correct variable or command that will look for the font. That is the major reason why I posted my question here.
As for the Latin test in the file: it is formatted in another font, which is why I hoped to used the font information to change only the Ethiopic parts.

Comment: Later I actually did find another code which exactly does what I want: 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38052638/visual-basic-macro-doesnt-record-font-choice-in-ms-word-2007)
But I can't create or use it in a script that changes all 245 characters. I get an error message claiming that the script is too long. Braking it up in several scripts doesn't work, at least not with my limited knowledge because the first script delete all specific font information, which I would need to run the other scripts correctly.

Comment: I may be a little naïve in this, but isn't this rather like a dictionary? 245 characters on the input side and 245 equivalents as output. So, you find one of the characters on to input and replace it with the equivalent. Worst case, you loop through all characters in the document. So any problem is limited to speed. Therefore the solution would be to first have the dictionary and then seek how to apply it. If this is correct, please add the "dictionary" to your question.

Comment: Use a format like `G< = 4609`. In fact, it would be even more helpful if you could quote the ASCII code for "G<" instead of its graphic representation, meaning ASCII left and Unicode right of the equal sign.

Comment: I do not really understand how treating this as a lexicon would help me. May be I should add that there are also many instances where an Ethiopic character is encoded with just a single Latin letter, e.g. "N" representing unicode "4624". So, if I have a script changing all instances of N into 4624, it will do this also in the Latin text.
I have already made a list of the representation, i.e. left side the original

Comment: I do not really understand how treating this as a lexicon would help me. May be I should add that there are also many instances where an Ethiopic character is encoded with just a single Latin letter, e.g. "N" representing unicode "4624". So, if I have a script changing all instances of N into 4624, it will do this also in the Latin text.
And many signs are not ASCII but extended, e.g. Ð = 4870. How could ASCII be used here?

Comment: Your idea is to commence with finding the font (AGF - Zemen). An `N` in that font would be converted to ChrW(4624) whereas an `N` in any other font wouldn't be touched.